# Genetic engineering, fawns, trees that are houses, animals that look like tables

Tags: story-identification

I read a book years ago about genetic engineering changing everything with houses that were actually engineered trees, things called fawns that took care of the house and watched the baby, a thing that looked like a table but I think it was a cop or a soldier. I would like to read it again but I don't remember the title or author.

Comment: How many years ago did you read it? Do you remember anything about the story? Was it about the development of genetically engineered houses and furniture and stuff, or the problems with such things? Did the story involve space travel or aliens?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing _The Muppet Show_. They had talking houses, talking trees, walking furniture etc.

Comment: On a sidenote (as it does not seem to be the story you're after): Frank Herbert's short story "The Tactful Saboteur" (1964) featured a genetically modified "chair-dog". An idea that Herbert re-used in one of the Dune-books.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the book you're looking for is [Copernick's Rebellion](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1150743.Copernick_s_Rebellion) by Leo Frankowski.

[image: image of the book]

Synopsis:

> Heinrich Copernick and Martin Guibedo came to the States as penniless
>   refugees after World War II. By 1999 they had made huge fortunes in
>   the field of medical instrumentation. But Heiny and his Uncle Martin
>   weren't just filthy rich, they were also the world's best gene
>   engineers. And their latest inventions could free Humanity from want
>   and oppressive governments forever. At least, that was the plan.
>   Imagine: Free homes with all the furnishings and utilities! Free food!
>   Even free babysitters! Heiny and Uncle Martin even thought they should
>   give their inventions away. Free. That's when their troubles began.